# Why does foreach skip one element from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate an array with `forEach` and, based on a condition, I do something.

For this question, I simplified the condition in order to try to understand what's going on.

I expect array `b = []` after the operation, but it is not, as it operates only on half on the elements. Why does this happen?

(This is not about removing everything from `b`, just trying to understand why it jumps the even indexes).

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var b = a.slice(0);

console.log('before b = ', b); // b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a.forEach(function (e) {
    if (e > 0) {
        b.splice(a.indexOf(e), 1);
    }
});


console.log('after b = ', b); // b = [2, 4, 6]

// but I expect b = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not. It goes through each and every item. The thing is what you do with array b. 
First you remove the index 0 from it which is 1. So now `b = [2,3,4,5,6]`.
Then index 1 which is 3 so `b = [2,4,5,6]`.
Then index 2 which is 5 so `b = [2,4,6]`.
The next indexes don't exist so in the end `b = [2,4,6]`.

To have the expected outcome use `b.indexOf(e)` in your splice call.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var b = a.slice(0);

console.log('before b = ', b); // b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a.forEach(function (e) {
    if (e > 0) {
        b.splice(b.indexOf(e), 1);
    }
});


console.log('after b = ', b); // b = [2, 4, 6]

// but I expect b = []
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Comment: I feel so dumb now. The thing is that, initially, there was only `a` array and I was slicing it directly, but still getting only half of the expected results. Later I added `b` in order to understand what was happening.
I think there was another problem inside the function which made it skip elements.

Comment: You are welcome, you have to be careful when you splice an array within the forEach

Answer (score 2):

You could take the index directly for splicing and make an log from the value an the array. You se, that the array becomes smaller than the index for splicing.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var b = a.slice(0);

console.log(b.join(' '));

a.forEach(function (e, i) {
    if (e > 0) {
        b.splice(a.indexOf(e), 1);
        console.log(i, ': ', b.join(' '));
    }
});

console.log(b); // b = [2, 4, 6]
```

To empty `b`, you need to look for the index of the array `b`, not `a` and splice it.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var b = a.slice(0);

a.forEach(function (e, i) {
    if (e > 0) {
        b.splice(b.indexOf(e), 1);
        //       ^
    }
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're splicing based on the index of the element from a, however b's indices are getting updated when you splice in it. You should try to splice from b based on the index of the element IN b.